# Python numpy array get first column values divide by 255 and store back

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, list, python-3.x, numpy

I have following numpy array

```
[[[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
   ..., 
  [  255   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]]]
```

**and this is a large array i just gave a sort example here**

I want to divide the first column first index value of every row by 255 and store it back to array,

**Ex** [  255   0   0 255] take first column first index value 255/255 and store it back, same for all rows

```
[[[  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
   ..., 
  [  1   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]
  [  0   0   0 255]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with in-place division:

```
>>> a = np.array([[255,255],[0,255]], dtype=int)
>>> a
array([[255, 255],
       [  0, 255]])
>>> a[:, 0] /= 255
>>> a
array([[  1, 255],
       [  0, 255]])
```

Comment: the array is 3d not 2d

Answer (score 1):

If you do something like `a[:, :, 0] = a[:, :, 0]/255`, the right-hand-side instantiates a whole new array, does the computation and then copies the result into `a`. You can skip this additional array instantiation and copying by using in-place division, which is done with the `/=` operator. Additionally, you may use `...` while indexing to mean "every other dimension", so that your code work on arrays of arbitrary shape. In total:

```
a[..., 0] /= 255
```

Additionally, you could consider using `//=` instead of just `/=`, to indicate that this is an integer division. These are equivalent for NumPy integer arrays, but not for NumPy float arrays.